# Select subsection of dendrogram using ggdendro

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dendrogram

Is it possible to plot just a subsection of a histogram using ggdendro. For example, how could I plot just the left most cluster in the following example:

```
require(ggplot2)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc)

ddata <- dendro_data(dhc, type="rectangle")

ggplot(segment(ddata),labels=rownames(USArrests))+ 
geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))+ 
theme_dendro()
```

[image]

bonus question: why do the state labels not show in the example above?

Answer (score 2):

The data:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc)
library(ggdendro)
ddata <- dendro_data(dhc, type="rectangle")
```

Create an index for the data which should be plotted (left cluster):

```
index <- seq(3, which(ddata$segment$y[-c(1, 2)] == ddata$segment$y[1])[2])
```

Plot (including x-axis labels):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(segment(ddata)[index, ]) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ddata$label$label[seq(sum(ddata$segment$yend == 0))])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Elizabeth: Your original code can be modified as follows to see x labels:

```
require(ggplot2)
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
ddata <- dendro_data(hc, type="rectangle")
ggplot() + 
geom_segment(data=segment(ddata), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
geom_text(data=label(ddata), aes(x=x, y=y, label=label, hjust=0), size=3) +
coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0.2, 0))
```